# Is xcopy used to copy (backup) svn repository?

Tags: windows, svn, batch-file, cmd, xcopy

If it is used what is the difference between svnadmin hotcopy and xcopy? And how can I run xcopy command for each repository in ReposFolder in windows batch file? My assumption is if it is useful to backup svn repository I can just xcopy ReposFolder to backup every repository inside that directory. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use xcopy or even better Robocopy to copy the SVN repositories, SVN will still work as usual if retored back. BUT it is always recommended to use the SVN admin copy/load to backup as it is more reliable and backsup all the revisions and if the copy interrupted in between, you will be able to just overwrite the revisions where you left.

Below is the syntax for robocopy. check `Robocopy /?` for mode options.

```
robocopy /e c:\repositories \\backupserver\svncopy
```

Cheers, G